# How can I get rid of text in a div when div width is set to 0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu that is set to width: 0px when page is loaded. After clicking on an icon, a jQuery script animates the width of the menu to be 100vw, therefore displaying all the menu items (links) nicely. My problem is, when the width is set to 0, the links inside the menu don't disapear like I want them to, they just get squished to the left. How can I make the links disappear completely when width is set to 0? And subsequentially, reappear when width is set to 100vw?

I have already tried making an if statement, where if the width is set to 0, then the links are empty but that doesn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance for anyone that helps.

```
<div id="menu">
    <div class="menu-item">
        <a href="#section-1" onclick="$('#on-menu').click();">Home</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <a href="#section-2" onclick="$('#on-menu').click();">Profile</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <a href="#section-3" onclick="$('#on-menu').click();">Contact</a>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

/*When icon (#on-menu) is clicked, this animates width from 0px to 100vw*/
isLarge = false;

$("#on-menu").click(function(){
    $("#menu").animate({width:(isLarge ? '0px' : '100vw')});
    isLarge = !isLarge;    
});

/*This, below, is what I tried but doesn't work*/

if($("#menu").width() == '0px'){
    $( ".menu-item" ).empty();
}

</script>
```

Comment: use `overflow:hidden` to hide the div content

Comment: Wow, that is so obvious. Thank you!!! I love you.

Comment: In addition to @sanjeev 's perfect answer, note that jQuery's `width()` method returns a number, so you would compare to `0`, not `0px`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `overflow:hidden` to hide the div content

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working  [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bwkhussp/)

By Default, overflow property will be `visible`. Thats why when the width is 0px, the text is visible. So, When we set overflow to `hidden`, the text will hide when the width is 0px.

Answer (score 1):

**If you can alter the mark-up, that would be my first suggestion**. Placing an inline element, like a `<span></span>`, inside the `<a>` element, will give you the freedom to apply styles to the inner content of the menu item.

**Note:** the icon will need to stay out of this inner `<span>`.

Then set a rule that hides the inner `<span>` content initially, onclick you can either toggle inline styles or add a new class with pre-set styles that will display the `<span>` content.

You could achieve a similar result with CSS hover styles by adding a transition to the `<span>`.

**E.g:** `transition: .7s;` on the inner `<span>`, then apply a new width to it when the parent element, the `<a>` tag, is hovered over. It should slide out nicely as the new width is applied. Of course, it'll revert back once you hover-off, but the idea is to allow CSS to handle any animations or transitions it can to negate some of that dependency on javascript.

**Otherwise try this:**

Paste this in your browser url bar...

```
data:text/html,<div id="menu"> <div class="menu-item"> <a href="#section-1" onclick="$('#on-menu').click();">Home</a> </div> <div class="menu-item"> <a href="#section-2" onclick="$('#on-menu').click();">Profile</a> </div> <div class="menu-item"> <a href="#section-3" onclick="$('#on-menu').click();">Contact</a> </div> </div>
```

Then add these styles, and play around...

```
.menu-item a {
    width: 0px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: gray;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper place to test the width of the element is in the `animate` callback, and you would use `0` instead of `0px`:

```
    $("#menu").animate({width:(isLarge ? '0px' : '100px')}, function(){
        if( $(this).width() == 0 ) { 
            $( ".menu-item" ).empty();
        }
    });
```

```js
isLarge = false;
$(".on-menu").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#menu").animate({width:(isLarge ? '0px' : '100px')}, function(){
        if( $(this).width() == 0 ) {
            $( ".menu-item" ).empty();
        }
    });
    isLarge = !isLarge;    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
    <div class="menu-item">
        <a href="#section-1" class="on-menu">Home</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <a href="#section-2" class="on-menu">Profile</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <a href="#section-3" class="on-menu">Contact</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

overflow:hidden will do the job.